# Sending an Image from a Javascript Client to a C# Server over Websocket and save it on file

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket

I'm trying to send an image from an Javascript client to a C# server and save that image in a file.
The websocket is established and i can send messages from client to server.
The message is a bytearray i get from the imagedata in Javascript.
My server gets the bytearray, but when i try to convert the bytearray into an image, i get a System.ArgumentException: "Invalid Parameter."
Here is my code from the Javascript client:

```
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
ar data2 = context.getImageData(0, 0, 800, 600).data;
var byteArray = new Array(data2);
connection.send(data);
```

And here is my Code from the C# Server:

```
        private static void OnAccept(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        try
        {
            Socket client = null;
            string headerResponse = "";
            if (serverSocket != null && serverSocket.IsBound)
            {
                client = serverSocket.EndAccept(result);
                var i = client.Receive(buffer);
                headerResponse = (System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)).Substring(0, i);
                // write received data to the console
                Console.WriteLine(headerResponse);

            }
            if (client != null)
            {
                /* Handshaking and managing ClientSocket */

                var key = headerResponse.Replace("ey:", "`")
                          .Split('`')[1]                     
                          .Replace("\r", "").Split('\n')[0]  
                          .Trim();

                // key should now equal dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==
                var test1 = AcceptKey(ref key);

                var newLine = "\r\n";

                var response = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" + newLine
                     + "Upgrade: websocket" + newLine
                     + "Connection: Upgrade" + newLine
                     + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + test1 + newLine + newLine
                     //+ "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat, superchat" + newLine
                     //+ "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13" + newLine
                     ;


                client.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response));
                var i = client.Receive(buffer); // wait for client to send a message

                using (Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(buffer)))
                {
                    image.Save("output.png", ImageFormat.Png);
                }


            }
        }
        catch (SocketException exception)
        {
            throw exception;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (serverSocket != null && serverSocket.IsBound)
            {
                serverSocket.BeginAccept(null, 0, OnAccept, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

My Exception occurs when i try to make my New Memorystream(buffer).
Does anyone have some help to solve this Problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible to send the image in Base64 format? It's a simple String easy to encode and decode...

Comment: That was the hint i needed! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcomed